# If false, search both true and false in Access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

```
SELECT id
FROM Activity
WHERE important = see below
```

`IF [Forms]![Search]![important] = false`, search for both `true` and `false`

`IF [Forms]![Search]![important] = true`, search for only `true`

I hope you understand what I want to do. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM Activity
WHERE important = @important OR @important = false
```

Or, maybe (just like ammoQ said)

```
SELECT id
FROM Activity
WHERE important OR NOT [Forms]![Search]![important]
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the shortest form, though not very readable:

```
SELECT id
FROM Activity
WHERE important OR NOT @important
```

Comment: it means: "your variable here"